# Negative values when calculating weighted Jaccard similarity

Tags: normalization, similarity, weighted-data, jaccard-coefficient

I have a bilateral dataset that includes countries and their the weight of their relation. I'd like to calculate the similarity of countries in 1) who their trade parterns are and 2) the weight of the relation to those partners. For this purpuse, I've calculated the weighted Jaccard similarity of the countries.

However, my data includes negative values. I know results from Jaccard similiary is supposed to range between 0-1, but I don't know whether results from the weighted Jaccard similiary should also be between 0-1. My question is if I need to normalize my data before running the weighted Jaccard similarity or if I can run it with negative values (which runs fine in code but also generates similarity results with negative values)?

If I should normalize, would min-max normalization be the best option?

Thank you!